# Using Pipedream, How do I get a Name and Content tag from the HTTP Trigger?

Tags: automation, pipe, pipeline

Using Pipedream, How do I get a Name and Content tag from the HTTP Trigger?

I could not find anything like this online and want people who know something to give me answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipedream exposes the event data from HTTP triggers in a JavaScript object called `event`, accessible in any code or action step.

By default, `event` contains some standard properties like `event.body` (the HTTP payload), `event.headers` (HTTP headers), and more. [1]

I'm not sure what you mean by "tag" in the context of HTTP, but once you send an event, you should be able to select it and view its contents just below the HTTP trigger itself, inspecting the values of the event:

[Image of event inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PBk2.png)

[1] https://docs.pipedream.com/workflows/events/#http

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know how to get the value out of a JSON object that will be in the body.

Comment: @JuvenileGoose the data from the HTTP payload will be exposed in any step in `event.body`. See https://docs.pipedream.com/workflows/events/#event-format